# Cypher: Create node and the relation in one query

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I need to create a neo4j cypher Query which first creates a node MyGroup, then a node MyDomain and at least a relation between them.

So far I;ve tried a few things and ended up with:

```
CREATE (p:Group { Name: "myGroup"}), (d:Domain {Name:"myDomain"}) 
WITH MATCH(g:Group {Name:"myGroup"}), (d:Domain {Name:"myDomain"}) 
CREATE(g)-[r: MEMBER_IN]->(d)
```

If I enter the Create and the MATCH separately, it works, but not in a combined query together with WITH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the identifier, `p` for the `Group` and `d` for the `Domain` you don't need to re-match those objects before you create the relationship.

You could simply do this

```
CREATE (p:Group { Name: "myGroup"}), (d:Domain {Name:"myDomain"}) 
CREATE (p)-[r: MEMBER_IN]->(d)
```

Alternatively, you could create them in a single statement.

```
CREATE (p:Group { Name: "myGroup"})-[r: MEMBER_IN]->(d:Domain {Name:"myDomain"})
```

Or, if any or all of the items already exist and you do not want them to be recreated you could do something like the following. `MERGE` will either `CREATE` items if they do not exist or `MATCH` them if they do already exist.

```
MERGE (d:Domain {Name:"myDomain"}) 
MERGE (p:Group { Name: "myGroup"})
MERGE (p)-[r: MEMBER_IN]->(d)
```